# Optimal Partition setup for Windows 7 on SSD

Tags: ssd

I'm setting up my system with Windows 7 right now, with knowledge that I am going to be getting a SSD in the future.  What optimizations/setup should I do now to make a smoother transition in the future?

1. Should I created two partitions - one for the OS and one for the data?  Assuming this is the case, I would be able to easily ghost my OS partition onto the SSD in the future.
2. If so, what should go on the OS drive besides the OS?  Program files?  If I install games or Visual Studio, should it go on the OS drive or the data drive?  I can see the SSD filling up fast if I install all my program files on there.
3. I've seen a few posts where people talk about leaving a portion of the SSD unformatted - is this something I should do?

Thanks!

Comment: Re 3: The cake is a lie. So is leaving part of the SSD unformatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Should I created two partitions - one for the OS and one for the data? Assuming this is the case, I would be able to easily ghost my OS partition onto the SSD in the future.`

   That's close, but no cigar (wow, I haven't used that line in years). What most bloggers say is OS in one *drive* (the SSD) and the data in another (the HDD).
2. `If so, what should go on the OS drive besides the OS? Program files? If I install games or Visual Studio, should it go on the OS drive or the data drive? I can see the SSD filling up fast if I install all my program files on there.`

   Keep in mind that most of the SSD tipsters are power users. The kind that leave their computer on at night because they expect their DVD to finish ripping, their download of a 200GB torrent, and rendering of an Adobe AfterEffects project to complete overnight. Because their computer is just that freaking good.

   Anyway. Yes, keep the program files on there. You'll be able to launch them a lot faster. Besides, keeping the program files on a drive different from the OS drive, unless they are [portable](http://portablefreeware.com/about), is messy.

   Your program files would take up quite a bit of space but since it's an SSD you probably have a second drive anyway to keep your data.
3. `I've seen a few posts where people talk about leaving a portion of the SSD unformatted - is this something I should do?`

   Comparable to cleaning out the registry. There really is no point, but it sounds useful. It isn't.

---

On a side note, Lifehacker has a great [guide](http://lifehacker.com/5586733/how-to-take-full-advantage-of-your-solid+state-drive) on the subject you ought to read. The Intel [SSD Optimizer](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18455) won't hurt either.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Regarding #1, I meant set up two partitions at this time on my existing HDD in anticipation of migrating to SSD in the future.  I suppose if I start out with my HDD it will also help me determine size requirements when I do purchase the SSD.

Comment: Migration? What I would do is use [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) with an external hard drive to back your stuff up, reinstall, restore the stuff from Easy Transfer, then move the Profile folder to the HDD. Windows won't work anyway if you move it to a different hard drive without reinstalling.

Comment: Really?  Is that something new?  I used to ghost XP partitions all the time.  I've been out of the techie game for a few years now...

Comment: Hard drives should work fine. It's hard drive controllers that can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should only put your programs that you think need a speed up on your SSD. That means, if you have a game that has really slow load times, you could reinstall it on your SSD.  I use my SSD just for the OS and for games with long load times, though I've heard of some people using it for photoshop, since that loads slowly.

Visual studio has a way of always installing some stuff on your C:, no matter what you do, which is aggravating. There's some forum posts out there about this, I'm looking into that since I'm about to install it myself.